# unable to connect to neo4j through

Tags: php, neo4j

I'm new in neo4j and i'm trying to use neoclient following the github 
instructions. I have installed neoclient with composer and neo4j 2.2.5.
Now i'm trying to use it with php. When i try to set up the connection with following:

```
<?php
 require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
 use Neoxygen\NeoClient\ClientBuilder;
 $client = ClientBuilder::create()
 ->addConnection('default', 'http', 'localhost', 7474)
 ->build();


 $query = 'CREATE (user:User {name:"Kenneth"}) RETURN user';
 $result = $client->sendCypherQuery($query)->getResult();
?>
```

I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Neoxygen\NeoClient\Exception\HttpException' with message 'Error on
>   Connection "default" with message "Client error response [url]
>   http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit [status code] 401
>   [reason phrase] Unauthorized"' in
>   C:\wamp\www\fantapappa\vendor\neoxygen\neoclient\src\EventListener\HttpRequestEventSubscriber.php
>   on line 65

and

> Neoxygen\NeoClient\Exception\HttpException: Error on Connection
>   "default" with message "Client error response [url]
>   http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit [status code] 401
>   [reason phrase] Unauthorized" in
>   C:\wamp\www\fantapappa\vendor\neoxygen\neoclient\src\EventListener\HttpRequestEventSubscriber.php
>   on line 65

can someone help me? where i'm wrong?

Comment: 401 is definitely a password issue as you didn't provided one, please accept Michael's answer if this is solved

Comment: right now i can't chek but I think this is the issue. as soon as i will accept the michael's answer. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to either provide a username (`neo4j`) and password (that you have to set in Neo4j-Browser upfront).

You you can disable auth (for development) in `conf/neo4j-server.properties`

```
dbms.security.auth_enabled=false
```

Comment: thanls, i'm not at home and i can't check i will do as soon as possible

Comment: I solved my problem only setting dbms.security.auth_enabled=false. I can not access with my usr and psw.

Comment: please adapt your question with the complete code you are using in neoclient with user and password, be sure that neoclient is supporting the built-in authentication of neo4j.

Comment: @Michael Hunger: I'm trying to install neo4j-shell-tools on windows but I have some problems. Can you helm me in some way?

Comment: Best ask in a new question. I have never tried it on windows though, mostly because I have no windows :)